# iOS: How to localize bunch .xib files using localized strings files by one ibtool command

Tags: ios, localization, xib, ibtool

I have this folder pattern:

```
-Xib
--en.lproj 
--- 1.xib
--- 2.xib
--- 3.xib
--ar.lproj
--- 1.xib.strings
--- 2.xib.strings
--- 3.xib.strings
```

How to inject the localized strings files in ar.lprog into the english xib files in en.lprog IN ONE ibtool command (not typing 3 commands)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution:

1. Put all the english `.xib` files and the localized `.strings` files in one folder, note the naming of strings file: `name.xib.strings`
2. Create an empty folder "result" in the same location.

open terminal and type in this command:

```
find . -name \*.xib | xargs -t -I '{}' ibtool --strings-file '{}'.strings --write result/'{}' '{}'
```